# Compare columns from two variables and do replacement using awk or join

Tags: bash, join, awk

I have two variables which contain tabular data. Now, var1 is having one field corrupted. So I need to correct it by mapping it with another variable which holds the mapping of it.

Here in `var1` 2nd column is corrupted.
Mapping to recover from corruption is present in `var2`.

Now I need to check the correct value of column2 of var1 from var2 and replace it in the result.

Contents of var1:

```
NODE 080e4441a6 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 18628c2a24 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 35c0ae9c35 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 5c9dc20a1a 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 7881cdedf6 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 79587f053e 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 859384e0cd 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 8d996c83fe 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE 9a0fbe4290 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE XXX-19     1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE YYY-20     2 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE bb2839f328 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE e0e440c477 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE ef21a2de3e 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
```

Contents of Var2:

```
18628c2a24 AREA-26
e0e440c477 AREA-21
YYY-20 YYY-20
XXX-19 XXX-19
8d996c83fe AREA-24
bb2839f328 AREA-22
9a0fbe4290 AREA-23
35c0ae9c35 AREA-25
ef21a2de3e AREA-27
7881cdedf6 AREA-32
080e4441a6 AREA-28
79587f053e AREA-30
5c9dc20a1a AREA-31
859384e0cd AREA-29
```

Desired result:

```
NODE AREA-28 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-26 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-25 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-31 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-32 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-30 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-29 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-24 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-23 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE XXX-19 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE YYY-20 2 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-22 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-21 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-27 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
```

I tried something like: but no help.

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($2 in a){ gsub($2,$1)}1' <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
```

Comment: Why are they in variables?

Comment: they are output of two different commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, try

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$2 in a{$2=a[$2]}1' <(echo "$var2") <(echo "$var1")
```

Note the order the variables are passed.

Answer (score 1):

***join*** + ***sort*** commands approach:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -o1.1,2.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8 <(sort -k2 <<< "$var1") <(sort -k1 <<< "$var2")
```

The output:

```
NODE AREA-28 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-26 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-25 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-31 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-32 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-30 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-29 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-24 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-23 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-22 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-21 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE AREA-27 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE XXX-19 1 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
NODE YYY-20 2 BLA ENABLED BLA1 BLA2 WORKING
```

---

*Details*:

- `sort -k2 <<< "$var1"` - sort `$var1` contents by the 2nd field
- `sort -k1 <<< "$var2"` - sort `$var2` contents by the 1st field
- `-1 2` - join on the 2nd field of *file1* (`var1`)
- `-2 1` - join on the 1st field of *file2* (`var2`)